# Whenever I am using a php variable as index on $_POST, isset() doesn't return true even if the index exist

Tags: php, html, input

Let's say I have a php variable `$post_index = 'myInput'`.

Assuming that `<input name="myInput">` exist, I then use this php variable on `$_POST[$post_index]`.

Whenever I submit the form and get the value from `<input name="myInput">` with the same name as the string in `$post_index` it works but when I use `isset()` to check if the form has an input with that name, `isset($_POST[$post_index])`, `isset()` returns nothing compared to `isset($_POST['myInput'])` which returns a 1.

The reason why I am trying to get this to work is because I have a while loop that checks if an input field exist on a dynamically increasing number of fields monitored by an incrementing variable.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit-data'])){
    $i = 1;
    $varcheck = 'part_number'.$i;
    echo "<script>alert('".isset($_POST[$varcheck])."');</script>"; //this shows nothing
    echo "<script>alert('".isset($_POST['part_number1'])."');</script>"; //this shows "1"
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
  <input name = "part-number1">
  <button type="submit" name="submit-data" id="submit-data">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Why is this the case and how do I work around this using only php?

Edit: Added the code

Edit: Answered - Typographical Error

Comment: is `isset($POST` your *real* syntax?

Comment: Are you using the php form method `POST`? And you have to always use `$_POST` don't forget the underscore.

Comment: Your question is way too unclear.

Comment: I added the underlines, my mistake

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner how can I make my question clear?

Comment: Show us your loop. Show us your form. Show us something.

Comment: From what I understood of your question you seem to be suggesting that you are unable to check that a particular field exists in the POST array by using a variable to reference it but that a statically typed reference to that field works OK. Is that correct? If that is so then there must be other factors at work here that are causing issues because using `isset( $_POST[ $somevar ] )` should work OK

Comment: Underscore and hyphen are different characters. And typo questions aren't useful to anyone else.

Comment: @mario man you are definitely right. I am really sorry about that

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: @waterloomatt yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are saying that when you check for the existence of an array key, it only works when you explicitly type in the key name. It does not work when you assign that key to a variable and then use that variable in the check, right?

If so, then the variable is not holding what you think it is. Here is a hard coded example showing that it would work if the variable holds the value you expect.

```
<?php

$array = [
    'key' => 'value'    
];

var_dump(isset($array['key']));

$keyStoredInAVariable = 'key';

var_dump(isset($array[$keyStoredInAVariable]));
```

Output

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

> Why is this the case and how do I work around this using only php?

You don't need a work around. You need to figure out why that variable isn't holding what you think it is. But you haven't given us enough info to help you figure out that reason.

Comment: I added a code snippet, would you mind checking it out?

Comment: Please note `part-number` is not the same as `part_number`.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending this data from html (within a form or an xmlhttrequest)?
or are you trying to set the `$_POST[]` variable manually as `$_POST[$post_index]`?
If I'm not wrong, your answer is the second one, $_POST only receive request sent by the `$_POST` protocol, you can't assign it as a common variable in the same php file